# Get domain whatever local or webserver

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wrote an ASP.NET web application. My application created a request with returning URL other e-commerce server. I want to get this.

http://www.stackoverflow.com/question/ask --> http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://localhost/stackoverflow/question/ask --> http://localhost/stackoverflow

I used `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`. But it's not OK for typing address by user.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [server variables collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  That is the source of this raw data that the `HttpApplication` gets from IIS.

I think the specific string you are looking for can be found with by `"http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]`

**EDIT**

Looking at your question again, this won't work for the "http://localhost/stackoverflow".  This is because it doesn't follow the same convention.  If you are using the convention that the public site is `http://www.domainname.com/` and your development site is `http://localhost/domainname`, then you could write a function that gets the site name like

```
 public static string GetDomainUrl(){
       var servername = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
       bool isLocalHost = serverName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("localhost);
       if(isLocalHost){
             var domain = serverName.Split(new Char[]{'/'})[1];
             return string.Format(@"http://localhost/{0}", domain);
       } 
       return string.Format(@"http://{0}", serverName);
 }
```

*Note: I wrote this in the SO textbox, so check it.*